# Why shell would start another shell process in this situation?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here's the code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$
cd $HOME && sleep 10 &
exit 0
```

now lets run `sh test.sh`

I got the result: 
`21936` which is the pid of the shell process I have ran.

and if I do `ps -ef | grep test.sh` within **10 seconds** which is the sleep time.

I got `root     21937     1  0 12:41 pts/0    00:00:00 sh test.sh`

Q1: It's supposed to be no `test.sh` but just a `sleep` process.  Why there's still a `test.sh` ?

Q2: It seems like the `test.sh` I grep out is not the same as the `test.sh` I ran in the terminal, depend on the `PID`. So how did the new `test.sh` come out?

---

Hi, there's another case of this, if I change

```
cd $HOME && sleep 10 &
```

to

```
cd $HOME; sleep 10 &
```

It will not act the same way, the `test.sh` will disappear right after executing `sh test.sh`, there's only one `sleep` process.

Comment: Background the job with `&` forks the process.

Comment: you mean `&` will fork the process it self? I used to think it will just fork the `sleep` in this case.

Comment: I think(!) what you see happens because of your "chaining" a shell built-in command together with an external command (sleep in this case). By specifying "built-in && external &" the shell runs the whole thing in the background and thus needs to fork itself (and not just "sleep"). In your second edit, you run two different commands (by using ";" instead of "&&"), albeit only "sleep" is forked.

Comment: You hit the point I think! Is there any documentation about "chaining built-in command together with an external command" ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But there is an almost duplicate question on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169289/3971).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(OK, I'll go out on a limb and turn my guess/comment into an answer.)

Since the `&&`-operator is essentially a shell-builtin, i.e. it needs to be processed by the shell, using it together with `&` will create a child process for the/a shell and not the individual parts of it (or just the last part of it as it looks, you'd expected).

That even happens when all commands chained with `&&` are external commands. For example, `sleep 3 && sleep 5 &` will also create a sub shell process.

The `;` just separates individual commands, as if they'd been written on separate lines. So in this case only the command that preceeds the `&` is forked ("send to the background").

(Of course, the original process that gets forked is always the shell - that is just the way how fork works - but in the second case, it is replaced with the executable of the actual command, `sleep` in your example).

Comment: "It is replaced with the executable of the actual command" — probably `exec` is at work here.

Comment: I have done some testing with `&&` and `&` and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell.

That is to say, the parent shell process is forked (in spawning the subshell).

You can easily test this with the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
print_subshell_level () { echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; }

printf "foreground: "
print_subshell_level

printf "background: "
print_subshell_level &
```

Output:

```
foreground: 0
background: 1
```

Comment: This is right. I know that `sh test.sh &` will put(fork) the `test.sh` to the background. But in this case the `&` is **in** the shell scripts `test.sh`, if this also put the `test.sh` to the background? I thought it is just the `sleep`

Comment: @louisthebang The process with command line `sh test.sh` is **forked**. You should first understand what is forking, which is different from "being sent to background". You should probably read the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call).

Comment: @louisthebang "I thought it is just the `sleep`." That doesn't make any sense. Even if executed in foreground, `sleep` will be a different process, since it's an external command. What's different about backgrounding is that `sh` is forked.

Comment: I added another case in the Question, please have a look. And yes I know what fork is, since I used that a lot in development. I think it's not the misunderstanding of `fork`, but the `&&` and `&` of `shell`.

Comment: @louisthebang I think what's happening here is the subshell calls `exec`, so the subshell is replaced by the `sleep` process.